# 2D Game, Performance Improvements?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

The game I'm developing is progressing, more and more elements are being added, but I'm of course facing new problems, one of which is the performance.

Currently, I'm having 3 threads, two of which perform calculations, the other one updates the canvas. These  three threads are synchronized with a CyclicBarrier, to have all calculations finished when beginning to draw the canvas.

I'm using several bitmaps in different sizes. In the drawing method, bitmaps are being rotated (by using drawBitmap-matrix combination with scaling/translating/rotating added into the matrix for "native" (i guess) management of it) and of course drawn. The problem I am facing is that whenever I have too many "moving and rotating" elements on the screen, it gets choppy.

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setTranslate(view.getX(), view.getY());
matrix.preScale((1.0f * view.getWidth() / view.getCurrentBitmap().getWidth()), (1.0f * view.getHeight() / view.getCurrentBitmap().getHeight()));
matrix.postRotate(view.getRotation(), view.getX() + view.getWidth()/2f, view.getY()  + view.getHeight()/2f);
mCanvas.drawBitmap(view.getCurrentBitmap(), matrix, mBasicPaint);
```

For example, this is how the player-object is being drawn according to the rotation and position:

```
private void drawPlayer(final Canvas mCanvas) {
    final Bitmap playerBitmap = mPlayer.getCurrentBitmap();
    mPlayer.nextFrame();
    if(playerBitmap != null) {
        if(mPlayer.getRotation() != 0) {
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.setTranslate(-mPlayer.getCurrentBitmap().getWidth()/2f, -mPlayer.getCurrentBitmap().getHeight()/2f);
            matrix.postRotate(mPlayer.getRotation());
            matrix.postTranslate(mPlayer.getX() +  + mPlayer.getCurrentBitmap().getWidth()/2f, mPlayer.getY()  + mPlayer.getCurrentBitmap().getHeight()/2f);
            matrix.postScale((1.0f * mPlayer.getWidth() / mPlayer.getCurrentBitmap().getWidth()), (1.0f * mPlayer.getHeight() / mPlayer.getCurrentBitmap().getHeight()), mPlayer.getX(), mPlayer.getY());
            mCanvas.drawBitmap(mPlayer.getCurrentBitmap(), matrix, mBasicPaint);
        } else {
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.setScale((1.0f * mPlayer.getWidth() / mPlayer.getCurrentBitmap().getWidth()), (1.0f * mPlayer.getHeight() / mPlayer.getCurrentBitmap().getHeight()));
            matrix.postTranslate(mPlayer.getX(), mPlayer.getY());
            mCanvas.drawBitmap(mPlayer.getCurrentBitmap(), matrix, mBasicPaint);
        }
    } else log("bitmap = null!");
}
```

(This is a kind of deprecated version, the .getCurrentBitmap() calls are reduced to one in the current version.)

How could I improve the performance? Should I create some sort of a "Loading..." screen, in which I pre-load EVERY bitmap (in its biggest size) and a pre-rotated version of each bitmap? (This would result in, if I go with 2-4 degree steps, 90-180 versions of each bitmap, which seems kind of.. a lot?) Or would this, with the rotated bitmaps stored as well, be too much on the memory? I don't know anything about OpenGL etc, this is why I'm using a SurfaceView and no other game engine, and I'm sure it has to work like this as well - somehow.

Comment: How about if you draw to an offscreen canvas then just flip them in order to render it.  Would having two canvases (canvasii?) require too much memory for your application?

Comment: But wouldn't this only make it worse? The drawing are done just fine, it's just that with a lot of rotations, it's slowing down. Drawing it onto another canvas, and afterwards copying the canvas would just require more CPU time, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a `Matrix` (matrix) and `Bitmap` (playerBitmap) object each time you call `drawPlayer` method. As far as I understand, you will call this method each frame. So, each frame, you are creating 2 large objects that need to be Garbage collected when you exit the method and this will slow down your frame rate. You can create only 2 objects `matrix` and `playerBitmap` as class level variables and refresh them on each call of `drawPlayer`, reducing the number of GC calls.

Comment: getCurrentBitmap does the following:     public Bitmap gettCurrentBitmap() {
        return mResourceBitmaps[mFrame];
    }, in mResourceBitmaps (for each ViewObject instance), the Bitmaps for each frame are loaded upon first initializing the object, so this should not be creating the bitmap but more likely return the reference? Or does "final Bitmap bitmap;" always create a whole new bitmap, even though it's just the reference?

Comment: From the scope of drawPlayer(), each time it is called, it creates a new Bitmap Object (inside this scope) and when this object is out of scope (drawPlayer() exits), this object is no longer referenced and is Garbage Collected (same for Matrix object)